# Button with a custom Background

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I have some buttons and I declared their background like this:

```
     <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundxml"
     />
```

and here is the backgroundxml:

```
    <stroke
  android:width="1dp"
 android:color="#FFFFFF" />

<corners android:radius="3dp" />

 <gradient
   android:angle="270"
   android:centerColor="#f1f1f2"
  android:endColor="#d1d3d4"
  android:startColor="#ffffff" />

</shape>
```

But now I have got a problem. I want to keep that Style But insted of Buttons with Text on them, I want to set a drawable on them. But when I change the Background from:

```
     android:background="@drawable/backgroundxml"
```

to

```
     android:background="@drawable/mybackbutton"
```

then I dont have the stroke and the start, center and endcolor in the background. So how can I set the Drawable but still keep the background?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with ImageButton. Something like this:

```
   <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/your_drawable"
        android:background="@drawable/your_background" />
```